# How to add item to formData.serializearray()?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to add another item to formData.serializeArray() and send formData with ajax to laravel controller.
Here is what I have tried:

```
    var formData = $('#form').serializeArray();

formData.push({"name":"inputValue", "value": '1' });

$.ajax({

   url: 'url',

   type:"POST",

   data:  formData,

   dataType : 'json',

   cache: false,

   success: function (data) {

   }
 })
```

In jquery, data pushed correctly. but, it doesn't send pushed data with ajax . it just send form data without new item.

Why it doesn't send pushed data with ajax?

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(formData)` after `formData.push`? Ideally this should work without issues

Comment: It shows new item in console.log(formData). but, it doesn't send it with ajax.

Comment: And about that question, No I pushed data  but it doesn't send data to controller.

Comment: Post your laravel code, the part where you parse the request

Comment: $info = $request->input('inputValue');

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
formData.push({"name":"inputValue", "value": '1' });
```

This should work can you try once again by `console.log(formData);`

Comment: `.push` must work correctly, and if it doesn't, then this won't too

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work.